# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class when using lombok

Tags: java, jackson

Strange problem happening when using `@Data` and `@NoArgsConstructor` from Project Lombok in a DTO.
Looks like Jackson is unable to serialize and deserialize classes with lombok annotations.

I'm little new to Lombok, but I was expecting that the library would generate the getters and setters, so Jackson would be able to serialize and deserialize the objects.

Short example:

**GetAllCustomersResponse.java**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class GetAllCustomersResponse {

    @JsonValue
    private List<GetAllCustomersResponseElement> customers = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addElement(GetAllCustomersResponseElement element) {
        this.customers.add(element);
    }

}
```

**GetAllCustomersResponseElement.java**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class GetAllCustomersResponseElement {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Date birthdate;

}
```

When a request arrives to retrieve the `GetAllCustomersResponse` (a list with all the Customers), this exception happens during Jackson's serialization:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class com.example.dto.GetAllCustomersResponseElement and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.example.dto.GetAllCustomersResponse["customers"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

AFAIK, 'No serializer found for class' **usually** happens when getters and setters do not exist in the class we want to serialize.

**If I write all the 'boilerplate' getters and setters, Jackson works properly.**

But, if I'm using `@Data` from Lombok, why there's no getters and setters available for Jackson?

From [Lombok docs](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data):

> **@Data**
>
> All together now: A shortcut for `@ToString`, `@EqualsAndHashCode`,
> `@Getter` on all fields, `@Setter` on all non-final fields, and
> `@RequiredArgsConstructor`!

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try including the `@AllArgsConstructor`.

Comment: it worked, many thanks..but how it worked?

Comment: I think Jackson uses the constructor for mapping if there are no Jackson mapping annotations set on the fields. Without looking at the actual Jackson source code, that's my best guess.